# Show file stream in browser in asp core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I wrote this code for show stream file in browser:

```
public IActionResult GetAvatar()
{
    var id = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();
    if (id > 0)
    {
        var user = dispatchers.QueryAsync(new GetUserByIdQuery { id = id }).Result;
        if (user.Success)
        {
            return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(this.finder.PathAvatarUserUploadFolder(), user.Result.Photo), "application/octet-stream");
        }
        return BadRequest(user.ErrorMessage);
    }
    return BadRequest("Id not valid");
}
```

this line : `return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(this.finder.PathAvatarUserUploadFolder(), user.Result.Photo), "application/octet-stream");`

But it have problem because when I enter the url in the browser, it downloads the file and it must go to downloads and open that file.

I need to open file in the browser. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you check the response headers using Chrome Developer tools or Fiddler, what is your `Content-Disposition` header set to? If its set to `attachment` the browser will always download the file. You can set the `Content-Disposition` to `inline` to tell browser to show the content inline if possible and offer download if it can't show content inline. This header can be set in different ways, but the simplest would be adding a header right before returning the file contents like below.

```cs
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = $"inline; filename={user.Result.Photo}";

return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(this.finder.PathAvatarUserUploadFolder(), user.Result.Photo), "application/octet-stream");
```